# Save cookies using cookie-parser and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I'm trying to save cookies using nodeJS and no luck

my code:

on app.js:

```
const cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser');
const session           = require('express-session');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

and then on index.js I'm trying to save order(which is an array of objects to a cookie:

```
router.post("/order", async function(req, res){
 order.push({data: req.body.order});
 var orderDetails = JSON.stringify(order);
    res.cookie('orderDetails', orderDetails, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 2});
...
...
...
```

But no cookie is stored in the browser

How can I fix that?

Comment: `maxAge` is in milliseconds, so `60*60*2` gives cookies only around 7 seconds lifespan. Also, you might be setting a cookie only for /order, try with option: `path: '/'`

Comment: Thank you so much Deltazero! it worked! Another question: If I'm using express-session and connect-mongo, Is there a way to store the same data I saved on the browser's cookies, but on the MongoStore? using this post request

Comment: Glad it works :-) About sessions & mongo, pls make a new question.